# Modify the HTML structure of a Joomla custom Module

Tags: joomla

I need to modify the HTML structure of a joomla module. I would like to create my custom module where I need to display the title below its content. 
This is the present HTML which is default format (rounded):

```
<div class="module_clipon">
 <div>
   <div>
     <div>
        <h3>Right Module</h3>
        <p>This is the content</p>                  
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need the above HTML to be like :

```
<div class="module_clipon">
    <p>This is the content</p>
    <h3>This is the title</h3>
</div>
```

Basically to bring the title below the module content. What would be the way to manipulate the HTML of a module in Joomla. I believe it is possible by using the modChrome. If anybody has a simple to implement solution, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will indeed want to handle this through custom module chrome. Within the folder of your template, create an `html` folder if one does not already exist. Within this folder, create the file `modules.php`. Then fill it with this code:

```
<?php 

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

function modChrome_titleonbottom( $module, &$params, &$attribs ) 
{
  echo '<p>' . $module->content . '</p>';
  echo '<h3>' . $module->title . '</h3>';
}
```

Finally, go back to your template to apply this chrome to your module position:

```
<div class="module_clipon">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="titleonbottom"/>
</div>
```

Use whatever module position name you need in the `name` parameter. Notice that the `style` parameter matches the `modChrome_` function name.

For more info: 
http://docs.joomla.org/What_is_module_chrome%3F
http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome

Comment: Thanks jlleblanc, your response is helpful. But I need to have other modules in the same module position with default rounded layout (4 divs wrapping) above and below it. any guess how to make this happen ?

Answer (score 2):

@Cruising2hell if you want to have alternative module layouts on the same position have you tried using module suffix params?. Like so..

```
<?php 

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

function modChrome_titleonbottom( $module, &$params, &$attribs ) 
{
  switch($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) :
     //My type of module 
     case 'titleonbottom':
       echo '<p>'. $module->content . '</p>';
       echo '<h3>' . $module->title . '</h3>';
     break;
     default:
     //Normal
       echo '<h3>' . $module->title . '</h3>';
       echo '<p>'. $module->content . '</p>';
     break; 
   endswitch;

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much ... that solves what I need .. Although I have another query, is it possible to have a similar solution for article component. If i can have different HTML layouts for articles to implement a 'portfolio' kind of page in Joomla to display the projects, while have regular articles on one page. I m not sure, pls suggest whats the best solution to have a projects page which would display projects in an easy manner. It must include Thumbnail, project detail and some client info.

Comment: If you are linking to the project pages with a menu, There is also a sfx for pages, you can play about with, just switch $this->params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' ); but make sure u set the suffix in your menu. Not the best of solutions! but will let u know if i come up with something better!

Answer (score 0):

I can't call it a problem.

Go to your main CSS file and insert this code:

```
.module_clipon h3 {
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 100px; 
     }

/* put a right height value where your h3 module header reach the bottom of the module content */
```

Answer (score 0):

i cannot call it a problem.

go to your main css file and insert this code :

```
.module_clipon h3 { 
      position: absolute; 
      margin-top: 100px; 
 }
```

/* put a right height value where your h3 module header reach the bottom of the module content */

:-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modified the return of the $module->content ? Because, if the module is a type of menu, the render is:

```html
<ul class="nav menu"><li>...</li></ul>
```

and if for example I need to put a class="list-inline" inside of `<ul>` and delete the nav and menu styles of the ul tag.